# how to update yarn if I install through windows installer?

Tags: windows, yarnpkg

I have installed yarn via [windows installer](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#windows-tab) sometimes back. Now I want to update it to latest version. How can I do that?

Answer (score 40):

The following worked for me:

```
npm i -g yarn
```

Comment: This did not work for me because it will install yarn to the npm global folder and not to "program files" where the installer has installed the previous version. (Best option for me was to download and rerun the installer)

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake That isn't bash specific. It should work on any OS with npm installed.

Answer (score 14):

Just download the new installer and rerun the setup.

Answer (score 8):

#### `choco upgrade yarn -y`

- 1. open powershell as administrator
- 2. run `choco upgrade yarn -y`

I stumble across this minutes ago, searching on the docs I found nothing but 'yarn self-update', I don't know if this is a deprecated command, but themselves do not recommend it. so I looked for the install options and it give the Chocolatey package. So just upgrade via it.